# How to Formatting XML data using C#, JQuery or HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

How i can get following XML data to easy understand format.

**Input XML Data**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user>
<details><name>xyz</name><class>mno</class><city>pqr</city></details>
<info><id>321</id><code>654</code></info>
</user>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user>
    <details>
        <name>xyz</name>
        <class>mno</class>
        <city>pqr</city>
    </details>
    <info>
        <id>321</id>
        <code>654</code>
    </info>
</user>
```

> Anyone idea how to do this using HTML,JQuery and C#.
>
> Thank you

Comment: You want to format the data in display in the UI?

Comment: Yes Mr. Chetan Ranpariya

Comment: And what code you have written for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below one(With C#).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace FormatXMLStringConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string rawStringXML = "<?xml version='1.0'?><user><details><name>xyz</name><class>mno</class><city>pqr</city></details><info><id>321</id><code>654</code></info></user>";
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(rawStringXML);
            xmlDoc.Save(sw);
            string formattedXml = sw.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(formattedXml);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Check and let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Glad To hear. Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I got snippet solution for that `XElement.Parse();` using  `linq`. Example as follow

```
string rawStringXML = "<user><details><name><firstname>pradip</firstname><lastname>Talaviya</lastname></name><class>mno</class><city>pqr</city></details><info><id>321</id><code>654</code></info></user>";
XElement message = XElement.Parse(rawStringXML);
Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
Console.Read();
```